# Libgdx - 3 images in a group, best practice - also overdraw

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to write a card game, that will have an image in the middle, a coloured border and potentially a symbol in the top left. I am using libgdx and a stage/scene2d.

The image will change depending on the suit (these are not your normal 52 deck type of cards), the border colour will change to match the suit, though this colour can be pre determined by the user so I can't pre-save coloured images (though I guess I could pre save about 15 diff colours and give the user a choice of 15) and the symbol will only be on some cards and not others.

[image: first card]
[image: second card]

As you can see from the two images I've added I have two diff images, border colours and symbols.

My question is relating to groups and overdraw.

1) I presume I should set up a group with 3 images in, and I'm hoping having this won't slow my game down as I will have potentially 30 cards on screen at once and 30 groups with up to 3 images in each could be a lot to draw. Is this right and will LibGDX be able to handle it fine?

2) How should I do the coloured border? Should I have the entire card a coloured rectangle and the image drawn on top? Would the draw method be trying to draw the coloured section underneath the image and thus wasting GPU/CPU time? A friend of mine said I could just have a white image, and then set the colour using RGB values in the code? Is this possible? That would mean I could only have a single jpg which would be much better for apk size.

3) Or should I ignore using a jpg image and try and draw the coloured square using ShapeRenderer?

Thanks, I hope these questions aren't too many in one post.

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course it will not slow you game - 90 (*30 groups x 3 textures*) sprites on screen are like *nothing* for (I guess) every framework - so LibGDX will do the thing also.

   **Although** it does matter how these graphics will be stored! Please use one [TextureAtlas](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html) with all textures instead of many textures in many files - you can prepare the Atlas by using [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) (for a basic usage like this *free version* will be ok).

   The reason of this is that if you are using many single [Textures](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html) LibGDX needs to switch graphic in GPU bufor (maybe it is not perfect term) before rendering each of them - if you have one big texture (including others) it does not need to switch anything because nothing changes in the buffor.

   To get more information about using TextureAtlas take a look at the [manual](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-textureatlases)
2. Yes you can "color" the [Actor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html) (like [Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html)) by using for example

   ```
   actor.addAction(Actions.color(new Color(1f,1f,1f, 0.2f), 2f));
   ```

   another approach is to have **1px x 1px** texture of every color (packed in your Texture Atlas) and just to change it's size. **There no reason to keep full size singe-colour textures** since it is great vaste of space and memory.
3. It is generally not good idea to use [ShapeRenderer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) - of course it is helpful sometimes but drawing sprites has a greater performance.

   **You are generally a little bit too scared about performance** but if you want to save your CPU avoiding ShapeRenderer seems to be good idea.